# How can I convert String to Double without losing precision in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How do I convert a string to double or float without losing precision

ex.

```
let stringNumber = "12.00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is `NSString(format:)` for the visual format of your value.

[Swiftstub sample](http://swiftstub.com/474330986)

To always show 2 digits visually use this:

```
NSString(format: "%.2f", value)
```

Comment: BIG Thanks, and this extension for that

extension Double
{
    func format(f: String) -> String
    {
        return NSString(format: "%\(f)f", self) as String
    }
}